# The template deployment 'Microsoft.Web-WebApp-Portal-3994ede8-a307' is not valid according to the validation procedure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

This is part of an exercise of MS Learning, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-release-pipeline/5-deploy-to-appservice.  On manual creation of Azure App Service, I am getting the error.

Please help with the Cause and Resolution

Steps to recreate:

azure.com >> Azure App Service >> +Add > add the project details like subscription, resource group etc... >> Review+Create, Below error:

> The template deployment 'Microsoft.Web-WebApp-Portal-3994ede8-a307' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'ca7e085f-a756-4344-bfe1-07444ff0fe0e'. See inner errors for details.

I'd like to know what is causing this error - and how I can avoid it?

Comment: What is your specific question? I'm assuming you want to know "What is causing this error", but you need to specify that. I edited your post for some grammar/formatting, but I can't assume the question you want to ask with this post.

Comment: @LetzCode  Just got the same issue just now ... will let you know if I find the issue.

Comment: @alteredinstance, thanks for correction. Your assumption is correct. I nee to know what is causing this error and how can it be avoided ?

Comment: I was using the Resource Group name as mentioned in the MS training module. After using another name for resource group. the error got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error by simply recreating webapp, and selecting another location. From Central Usa to South Central USA. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

So looking at the output in the network tab of the browser i saw this:

`The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one.`

So deleted the app service plan/web app and now it works.

MS, please show us the error ...

Comment: @alteredinstance Yes, it works since you can't have mixed environments. Hopefully MS will let this error message be shown in the UI at some point.

Comment: choose a different resource group, which resolved the error

Answer (score 0):

Changing the location, helped me in fixing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue so I changed the location from "East US" to "East US 2" and it also worked for me.